# How to measure the length of a D3.JS node's attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attributes

I have several paths I've made in D3.JS and on mouseover I call this mouseover function to get the attributes of that path and store them in variables. Then I try to measure the length of the level attribute and console.log it, however Im getting an error: 
[image]

I'd also like to use the .slice(-1,1) method to get the last figure in that value attribute but this doesn't work either.
I think the attribute needs to be read as a string in order to do these things. but when I call .toString() on circleLevel I'm still getting this error.

here is the mouseover function:

```
 function mouseover(){
var circleName = d3.select(this).attr("name");
var circleSize = d3.select(this).attr("size");
var circleLevel = d3.select(this).attr("level");
var levelLength = circleLevel.length();
console.log(circleLevel.length());
```

}

here it is on JS fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/RL_NewtoJS/ryyt6ruj/3/

Comment: It would be nice to have a fiddle to fully answer the question, but for your first point, it's trying to evaluate 5, 3 and 5 as functions, which should tell you that `.length` is a property, not a function. `circleLevel.length` (do not invoke it with `()` ) will give you what you need.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RL_NewtoJS/ryyt6ruj/3/

Comment: I am confused about what you mean by length. You are attaching your own custom length attribute of the format 'x-y-z' and it seems like you are able to access that just fine. Try `console.log(this.getTotalLength())` in your mouseover handler. Is this the length you are trying to get at?

Comment: I'm trying to get the length of the level attribute ( format 'x-y-z' or  'x-y' ) ...which will be either 5 or 3

Comment: Then in your fiddle, if you change that last console.log in the mouseover handler to just `console.log(levelLength)` then that is your number. Now, what are you trying to slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, string length is a prop, not a method. So

```
circleLevel.length()
```

should be

```
circleLevel.length
```

The error is because it's trying to call the `length`, the Number, as a function: `5() // invalid`

Regarding obtaining the last character, either use

```
circleLevel.charAt(circleLevel.length - 1)
```

or

```
circleLevel.substr(circleLevel.length - n) // to get last n characters
```